# Convert varchar to Decimal Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, average

Please can some one help me with this simple sql query

```
SELECT avg(CAST(NULLIF(Sim1SS,0.0) as DECIMAL)) as MTN ,
avg(CAST(NULLIF(Sim2SS,0.0) as DECIMAL)) as Vodacom

FROM [Networks].[dbo].[Device]
```

I am getting the following error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

and here is an example of the SS column:

```
28,99
10,99
11,99
NULL
NULL
31,99
31,99
NULL
```

Comment: replace `,` with `.`

Comment: `SELECT avg(CAST(NULLIF(REPLACE(Sim1SS,',','.'),0.0) as DECIMAL)) as MTN `gives me same error:

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems. First of all when you using NULLIF on a string datatype you are implicitly converting it to a numeric datatype. You have specified 0.0 as a second parameter. SQL Server does not know what to choose and it perhaps selects a `float` or something else. NULLIF should be called after you convert the string to number

Secondly, you have not specified the precision and scale for your DECIMAL data type. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187746.aspx) the default precision and scale of the DECIMAL data type is 18,0. If you have not specified the scale the numbers will be truncated.

So, the correct syntax should be:

```
SELECT avg(NULLIF(CAST(Sim1SS as DECIMAL(18,2)), 0.00)) as MTN,
       avg(NULLIF(CAST(Sim2SS as DECIMAL(18,2)), 0.00)) as Vodacom
FROM [Networks].[dbo].[Device]
```

BTW, if your regional settings for decimal symbol is not a period (`.`) then you need to do a replace:

```
SELECT avg(NULLIF(CAST(REPLACE(Sim1SS, ',', '.') as DECIMAL(18,2)), 0.00)) as MTN,
       avg(NULLIF(CAST(REPLACE(Sim2SS, ',', '.') as DECIMAL(18,2)), 0.00)) as Vodacom
FROM [Networks].[dbo].[Device]
```

If your data is not sanitized you need to use ISNUMERIC function, like this:

```
SELECT avg(NULLIF(case when isnumeric(Sim1SS)=1 then CAST(REPLACE(Sim1SS, ',', '.') as DECIMAL(18,2)) end, 0.00)) as MTN,
       avg(NULLIF(case when isnumeric(Sim2SS)=1 then CAST(REPLACE(Sim2SS, ',', '.') as DECIMAL(18,2)) end, 0.00)) as Vodacom
FROM [Networks].[dbo].[Device]
```

Comment: Ok then, you've got non numeric values then. You need to use ISNUMERIC function to test together with CASE